# react-native-autocomplete-dropdown component in Android isn't scrollable

Tags: react-native, autocomplete, dropdown

The following code works fine under iOS, it also displays correctly on Android but the suggestion list are not scrollable. Btw. this is the example from the official documentation only enhanced by more data and it is not working as expected. Can anyone help?

```
import { AutocompleteDropdown } from 'react-native-autocomplete-dropdown';
.
.
.

return (<View >

            <AutocompleteDropdown
                clearOnFocus={false}
                closeOnBlur={true}
                closeOnSubmit={false}
                initialValue={{ id: '2' }} // or just '2'
                onSelectItem={( item ) => item && setSelectedItem( item.id )}
                dataSet={[
                    { id: '1', title: 'Alpha' },
                    { id: '2', title: 'Beta' },
                    { id: '3', title: 'Gamma' },
                    { id: '4', title: 'Delta' },
                    { id: '5', title: 'Epsilon' },
                    { id: '6', title: 'Zeta' },
                    { id: '7', title: 'Eta' },
                ]}
            />
    </View>);
```

I was looking through the documentation on github at https://github.com/onmotion/react-native-autocomplete-dropdown but was unable to find anything helpful.

Answer (score -2):

You are missing flex: 1 in you parent component since flex is not defined scroll wont work please add flex: 1 in you view component

[working example](https://snack.expo.dev/@ashwith00/autocomplete)

eg:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { AutocompleteDropdown } from 'react-native-autocomplete-dropdown';

export default function App() {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = React.useState();
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <AutocompleteDropdown
        clearOnFocus={false}
        closeOnBlur={true}
        closeOnSubmit={false}
        initialValue={{ id: '2' }} // or just '2'
        onSelectItem={(item) => item && setSelectedItem(item.id)}
        dataSet={[
          { id: '1', title: 'Alpha' },
          { id: '2', title: 'Beta' },
          { id: '3', title: 'Gamma' },
          { id: '4', title: 'Delta' },
          { id: '5', title: 'Epsilon' },
          { id: '6', title: 'Zeta' },
          { id: '7', title: 'Eta' },
        ]}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```